# how to compute the growth rate in Power Bi using Dax?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to have a column in power bi showing the growth rate of sales. I have a table like

| year | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1395 | 123 |
| 1396 | 232 |
| 1397 | 23 |
| 1398 | 908 |
| 1399 | 678 |
| 1400 | 34 |

the growth rate is (this year - previous year)/previous year

could you please guide me how I can do this?

When I use the growth the data is like below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a calculated column like this:

```
growth = 
VAR _currentcount = 'Table'[count]
VAR _currentyear = 'Table'[year]
VAR _previouscount =
    CALCULATE ( 
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[count] ) , 
        ALL ( 'Table' ) , 
        'Table'[year] = _currentyear - 1
    )
RETURN
IF (
    NOT ISBLANK ( _previouscount ) ,
    DIVIDE ( _currentcount , _previouscount ) - 1
)
```

or a measure like this, to be used with your `year` dimension:

```
growth_measure = 
VAR _currentcount = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[count] )
VAR _currentyear = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[year] )
VAR _previouscount =
    CALCULATE ( 
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[count] ) , 
        ALL ( 'Table' ) , 
        'Table'[year] = _currentyear - 1
    )
RETURN
IF (
    NOT ISBLANK ( _previouscount ) ,
    DIVIDE ( _currentcount , _previouscount ) - 1
)
```

Giving this result:

[image]

All depending on your needs.

Comment: Why as calculated Column? Why not as a measure?

Comment: @msta42a I added a measure too, but without knowing more about the requirements it doesn't really make a lot of difference to the answer.

Comment: thank you. but the growth is shown just for the first year :(

Comment: I want to show the growth rate in a table or line chart. So I think the column is more useful. isn't it?

Comment: If it only shows for the first year then you might have the `NOT ISBLANK` clause wrong. With your provided sample data, that is the row I specifically blank out since it doesn't make sense to measure % growth for the first year. The function also blanks if have several rows per year in your actual dataset, then the `SELECTEDVALUE` functions do not work, and you need to aggregate using e.g. `SUM` instead.

Comment: If you want to use it in a line chart, the measure is fine since it does not take up additional resources in your data model unless invoked in a visualization. Use `year` as axis and the `growth_measure` as values in your chart.

Comment: I updated the question and you can see there is no blank data and yet shows just for the first year.

Comment: So there are more than one row per year? Then you need to use an aggregator like `SUM ( 'Table'[Count] )` instead of `SELECTEDVALUE` to get your counts.